# Perl Need to find Full Path of Directory/File

Tags: perl, recursion, directory

I am recursively walking through directories but when a directory is empty and the script moves on to the next file/directory in the original directory, the Full Path stays in that empty directory.  I need it change to the one I am currently searching through even when I go back up some levels.

My Script:

```
# specify the directory where you want to start the search
my $directory = $ARGV[0];
my $directoryCount = 0;
my $directory = shift;
my $searchfile = shift;
my @directories;
my $tarOutput;

# Calling the Subroutine, which searches the File
readDirectory($directory);

sub readDirectory
{
    # Open and close the directory
    opendir(DIR, $directory) or die("ERROR: Couldn't open specified directory $!");
    my @files = grep { $_ !~ /^\.{1,2}$/ } readdir DIR;
    closedir DIR;

    print "------------------------------------------------------------------------    \n\n";

    foreach my $currentFile (@files)
    {
        print "Current File: ", $currentFile, "\n\n";

        #directory currently searching through
        print "Searching in $directory\n\n";

        my $fullPath = "$directory/$currentFile";
        print "FULL PATH: $fullPath\n\n";
        if ( -d $fullPath )
        {
                print "Found New Directory: ", $currentFile, "\n\n";
                push (@directories, $currentFile);
                $directoryCount++;
                print "Current number = $directoryCount\n\n";
                print "Directories: @directories \n\n";
                # The Subroutine is calling hisself with the new parameters
                $directory = $fullPath;
                readDirectory($directory);
        }

        elsif ( $currentFile =~ /\.tar.gz$/i || $currentFile =~ /\.tar$/i ||     $currentFile =~ /\.gz$/i)
        {
                print "File: ", $currentFile, "\n\n";
                my $tarOutput = `tar -tvzf $currentFile`;
                print $tarOutput, "\n";
        }

        print "-----------------------------------------------------------------------\n\n";
    }
}
```

Here is my output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File: AAA

Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs

FULL PATH: /home/gackerma/Logs/AAA

Found New Directory: AAA

Current number = 1

Directories: AAA

------------------------------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File: Dir1

Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs/AAA

FULL PATH: /home/gackerma/Logs/AAA/Dir1

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File: file

Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs/AAA

FULL PATH: /home/gackerma/Logs/AAA/file

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File: adstatlog.299

Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs/AAA

FULL PATH: /home/gackerma/Logs/AAA/adstatlog.299

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File: zzz

Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs/AAA

FULL PATH: /home/gackerma/Logs/AAA/zzz

-----------------------------------------------------------------------

Current File: adstatlog.tgz

Searching in /home/gackerma/Logs/AAA

FULL PATH: /home/gackerma/Logs/AAA/adstatlog.tgz

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Dir1, files, adstatlog.299, zzz, and adstatlog.tgz are all actually in the original directory /home/gackerma/Logs, but the script thinks they're in the empty subdirectory AAA.

I know it's this part:

```
print "Current File: ", $currentFile, "\n\n";

#directory currently searching through
print "Searching in $directory\n\n";

my $fullPath = "$directory/$currentFile";
print "FULL PATH: $fullPath\n\n";
if ( -d $fullPath )...
```

But I don't know what to do to make it change the new Full Path to the new (original) directory if nothing is found in a subdirectory...

Help please?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/1692697/55857 for some alternatives to both `Wheel::Reinvent` and `File::Find`.

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel by writing your own recursive directory sub? Instead, you should be using either the `File::Find` or `File::Find::Rule` module, which handles all of the messy recursion details which unless this is being done for an assignment.

Comment: NB: File::Find has quite a few problems associated with it.  It just doesn't work like it should.

Answer (score 0):

You're using one global variable named $directory which you never change.

```
sub readDirectory
{
        ...
}
```

should be

```
sub readDirectory
{
        my ($directory) = @_;
        ...
}
```